# Calculate column value in table1 based on the value from column in table2

Tags: sql

Hi I am stuck in calculating columns. I tired of googling similar questions and had no luck.

Look at the following tables.

**ConfigTable**

```
-------------------------------
|KeyName        | KeyValue    |
-------------------------------
|MinimumMargin  | .50         |
|MaximumMargin  | 2           |
-------------------------------
```

**PriceTable**

```
-------------------------------
|SKU  |Price   | Shipping     |
-------------------------------
|001  | 23    | 1.5         |
|002  | 20    | 1.5         |
-------------------------------
```

I want to get result as under:

```
SELECT SKU, SUM(PRICE+SHIPPING) + 'ConfigTable.MinMargin' as CalcPrice FROM PRICE
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's a desired result? are you really storing prics/shipping values as string like '$23' ?

Comment: No. This was just for example purpose. I store as 23 (float) type. I modify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get the `sum` of the price and shipping for each `sku` and then use a `CROSS JOIN` to join `configTable` to add the `keyValue`:

```
select p.sku,
  p.CalcPrice + (c.KeyValue) CalcPrice
from
(
  select p.sku,
    sum(p.price + p.shipping) CalcPrice
  from priceTable p
  group by p.sku
) p
cross join configTable c
where c.keyname = 'MinimumMargin'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b99ec/8).

If the `KeyValue` is a varchar, then you will need to convert it so you can add it to the `CalcPrice`:

```
select p.sku,
  p.CalcPrice + convert(c.KeyValue, decimal(10, 2)) CalcPrice
from
(
  select p.sku,
    sum(p.price + p.shipping) CalcPrice
  from priceTable p
  group by p.sku
) p
cross join configTable c
where c.keyname = 'MinimumMargin';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27ba1/8)

Comment: The data types you are using are not compatible with the ones from @Mehboob.